# PowerShell should be returning object[] from pipe?

Tags: powershell

Given this function:

```
> function Get-ArrayOfArrays() {
    (1,2),(3,4) | % { $_ }
}
```

I'd expect the return type to be an array of arrays.  However, it appears that the inner arrays are being expanded into the pipe:

```
> Get-ArrayOfArrays | % { $_.GetType().Name }
Int32
Int32
Int32
Int32
```

In fact, running the pipe inline will produce these results:

```
> (1,2),(3,4) | % { $_ }
Object[]
Object[]
```

I've found that if I use the return keyword inside the foreach, I can achieve the desired result:

```
> function Get-ArrayOfArraysWithReturn() {
    (1,2),(3,4) | % { return $_ }
}

> Get-ArrayOfArraysWithReturn | % { $_.GetType().Name }
Object[]
Object[]
```

This behavior seems to be "If returning from a function with uncaptured objects, and those objects happen to be arrays, then expand them".  Is this one of those "do-what-is-useful-most-of-the-time" design decisions?  Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(1,2),(3,4) | % {$_}
```

results in your function outputting (1,2) and (3,4) - the same as this function would:

```
function foo { 
    1,2
    3,4 
}
```

The kicker is that each of these arrays have their content's unrolled (flattened) again as part of the process of a function outputting objects  e.g.:

```
PS> foo | %{$_.GetType().Name}
Int32
Int32
Int32
Int32
```

This is similar to what you see on the host when you execute this:

```
PS> 1,2
1
2
```

The array is unrolled such that each element of the array is displayed. The following should do what you want:

```
function Get-ArrayOfArrays() { 
    (1,2),(3,4)
}
```

When (1,2),(3,4) hits the function output it is unrolled once, outputting (1,2) and (3,4). Another technique you can use to work-around collection unrolling is to wrap a collection within another single element collection using the `,` operator to preserve the shape of the original collection e.g.:

```
PS> function foo { ,((1,2),(3,4)) }
PS> foo | gtn
Object[]
```

Comment: The array flattening is sometimes a little bit tricky but very helpful.

Comment: Yeah, most of the time you don't think about it (good for the Powershell team) but when dealing with arrays of arrays and maintaining that shape, you have to jump through a hoop or two.

Comment: Ah, there are two function boundaries being hit, so it's unrolled twice.  Makes sense - thanks for the great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to ask a similar question, namely "How do you prevent PowerShell from unrolling /joining / concatenating arrays?".

What I found out is that the interactive interpreter does an extra step of unrolling **before** it prints the results in the console:

For example

```
> (1, 2), (3, 4)
1
2
3
4
```

Which means it was already unrolled once:

```
[ 1, 2 ] ++ [ 3, 4 ] == [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Therefore what the interpreter prints is not necessary the **real** output of the code.

For example, the following code

```
1, 2, 3 | ForEach-Object { $_, ($_ * 2) }
```

takes the first three integers and gives us a list of two numbers `[ x, x * 2 ]` for each one.  The result is:

```
[ 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6 ]
```

However I wanted the following output:

```
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 6 ] ]
```

I used the comma `,` operator as Keith Hill suggested:

```
$list = 1, 2, 3 | ForEach-Object { , ($_, ($_ * 2)) }
```

Since we returning an array of, array of, int's for each input:

```
1   -> [ [ 1, 2 ] ]
2   -> [ [ 2, 4 ] ]    
3   -> [ [ 3, 6 ] ]
```

We expect it to be unrolled once only so that `$list` equals:

```
[ [ 1, 2 ] ] + [ [ 2, 4 ] ] + [ [ 3, 6 ] ] == [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 2, 4 ], [ 3, 6 ] ]
```

And we can test that it is

```
> $list[0]   #  get first element of list, should be [ 1, 2 ]
1
2
> $list[2][1]  # from the third elem, [ 3, 6 ], get 2nd elem, should be 6
6
```

However, when the interpreter prints the list, it unrolls it once more:

```
[ 1, 2 ] ++ [ 2, 4 ] ++ [ 3, 6 ] == [ 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6 ]
```

so we get

```
> $list
# prints [ 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 6 ]
```